# How to exclude certain vertices in gremlin titan

Tags: titan, gremlin, tinkerpop3

For example I want to exclude some vertex ids while querying.

**Step 1:** I am taking user followed by me(1234):

> g.V(1234).outE("following")

*Output :* 9876,3246,2343,3452,1233,6545

---

**Step 2:** I have to exclude or remove certain ids

> users = [3452,1233,6545];
>   g.V(1234).outE("following").inV().except(users)

*Output :* 9876,3246,2343.
It should come like this but the except function didn't work. Is there any solution to filter specific vertex ids.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's as easy as:

```
users = [3452, 1233, 6545]
g.V(1234).out("following").hasId(without(users))
```

Or just:

```
g.V(1234).out("following").hasId(without(3452, 1233, 6545))
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. My version is overly complicated compared to this one!

Comment: The above method didn't work for me.is there any other way.

Comment: Not error.the given vertices not getting filtered.For ex I am giving like this 1.g.V().out("following") ==> v[204804320]
==>v[204808416]
==>v[286724152]

Comment: 2-step : g.V().out("following").hasId(without(204804320, 204808416)). The output is  : 
==>v[204804320]  
==>v[204808416]  
==>v[286724152]

Comment: Sorry forget to add quotes like this g.V().out("following").hasId(without("3452","1233"));thanks its working

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`where`](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#where-step) step to filter the vertices. This allows you to exclude vertices based on their id. The following query should give you the expected result:

```
users = [3452,1233,6545];
g.V(1234).out("following").where(__.not(hasId(within(users))))
```

Note, that I used `out()` as a short form of `outE().inV()` which allows to directly traverse to the neighbor vertices.